# Jenkins declarative pipeline: dynamically populate text and multi-line text parameters based on user selection

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, devops, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

i have the following Active Choice parameter. When the user selects a value, i want to either display a string parameter or a 'text'(multi-line) parameter with defaults.
Is this possible?

```
properties([
    parameters([
        [
            $class: 'ChoiceParameter',
            choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT',
            name: 'rtArgs', 
            script: [
                $class: 'GroovyScript',
                script: [
                    sandbox: true,
                    classpath: [],
                    script: '''
                        return ['Java','Python', 'Cmd']
                    '''
                ]
            ]             
        ]
    ])
])
```

In my pipeline i have the following

```
agent any 
parameters{
    string(name: 'cmdArgs', defaultValue: cmdDflt)
    text(name: 'cpArgs', defaultValue: cpDflt)
}
```

If the user selection is java or python, I want to display (or create dynamically) only the text parameter, otherwise the string parameter.

Is something like this possible with pipeline + declarative?

Comment: It is possible, but you have to implement it in JavaScript, where you catch the selection event and modify the page DOM accordingly — you hide/unhide the string/text parameters depending on the selection.